# How to add [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute at an assembly-level in a .Net Standard 2.1 project

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage, coverlet, dotnet-test

I have a .NET Core application which has got one .NET Standard 2.1 project in it. I am using Coverlet to get the code coverage in Cobertura format.

I am using "coverlet.msbuild" nuget package in all my Test projects.

I want to add `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute at a assembly-level so that coverlet ignores this project while performing the analysis.

I cannot find the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in .NET Core / .NET Standard projects.

I tried adding the below tag in the project's `.csproj` file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but still no luck.

The only workaround for me is to add thr `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute manually in all the class files which is not the best way.

Comment: The above seems to work for me on MacOS using Jetbrains Rider/dotcover.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for .NET 6. I suspect it will work for .NET Core 3.1+

Add the following to the csproj file

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Or this in any file in the project for the assembly

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
```

Comment: Using the attribute, I'm running into [CS0592](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0592?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0592))